# Extracting members (for one column) and their scores summed (for another column)

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to ask for your advice on the following.

Sample data:

```
structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), member = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), class = "factor"), X1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L), variable.labels = structure(character(0), .Names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L)
```

The above sample data look like:

```
+-------+--------+----+
| group | member | X1 |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | A      | 0  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | B      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | B      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | C      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | D      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | A      | 0  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | A      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | A      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | A      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | D      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | D      | 0  |
+-------+--------+----+
```

**What I'm looking for:**

```
+-------+--------+----+
| group | member | X1 |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | A      | 0  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | B      | 2  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | C      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 1     | D      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | A      | 3  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | B      | 0  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | C      | 0  |
+-------+--------+----+
| 2     | D      | 1  |
+-------+--------+----+
```

Above, you can see one row for each member (A, B, C, D) and another column with the sum of X1 from the raw data.

Comment: `df1 %>% group_by(group, member) %>% summarize(X1 = sum(x1))`

Comment: You also may need `complete` as well to fill in groups where there is no data (e.g., group 2 members B and C)